# Gitlab: Can't push to master only

Tags: git, gitlab

I can't find a reson for being able to push changes in any branch other than master. I mean, I have master branch which I created by pushing my code to gitlab. Than, any tentative to push a change to master branch fails. Nevertheless, I duplicated my master branch with another branch named develop and on it I can push my changes. To make simple, let me put all I am doing after googling for while:

```
C:\dev\test>git fetch --all
Fetching origin

C:\dev\test>git reset --hard origin/master
HEAD is now at 64031f0 just created by generator

... some changes via my editor ....

C:\dev\test>git commit -a -m "changed project name"
[master 5abf2f2] changed project name
 1 file changed, 5 insertions(+), 5 deletions(-)

C:\dev\test>git push -u origin/master
fatal: 'origin/master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

C:\dev\test>git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 365 bytes | 365.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Error: This is the master branch, and the commit has no merge request
remote: 64031f03f1723e3399ad467dbbb536942fe144f0 5abf2f29e0ced51289d1fcd684b1510acd354764 refs/heads/master
To ssh://gitlab.mycomp.net:2222/myportfolio/mycomp-app-sf-just-test.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@gitlab.mycomp.net:2222/myportfolio/mycomp-app-sf-just-test.git'

C:\dev\test>git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 365 bytes | 365.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Error: This is the master branch, and the commit has no merge request
remote: 64031f03f1723e3399ad467dbbb536942fe144f0 5abf2f29e0ced51289d1fcd684b1510acd354764 refs/heads/master
To ssh://gitlab.mycomp.net:2222/myportfolio/mycomp-app-sf-just-test.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@gitlab.mycomp.net:2222/myportfolio/mycomp-app-sf-just-test.git'
```

In few words, most of answers I saw around tells either to use git push -u or to unprotect the branch. Now my gitlab project branch is unprotected and as you can see I am using -u

Answer (score 9):

The issue here is by default master branch is protected one.
You can change that setting if you want to using **"Unprotect" button under Repository settings -> Protected branches.**
Also, you can change branch accessibility settings for merge , push for maintainer, developer level too.
Refer screen for more detail.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is probably related to how [permissions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html) work with Gitlab.

If you go down the list of my linked doc, you'll see that:

```
Push to protected branches
```

is only allowed to people having *Maintainer* (was Master prior to *11.0*) and *Owner* permissions.

---

> *can't find a reson for being able to push changes in any branch other than master*

This is because only master is protected by default. Therefore, you would need elevated permissions in order to push directly on that branch.

Comment: well, as my last phrase stated, "Now my gitlab project branch is unprotected and as you can see I am using -u", I unprotected but I am still unable to push to the master

Comment: @JimC Your `master` branch is unprotected ? You're sure about that ?

Comment: @JimC Also are you the owner of that branch ?

Comment: 1 - Under settings/ Repository / Protected Tags / Protected tag (0) I read:  There are currently no protected tags, protect a tag with the form above.
2 - Under Settings/Audit events/ Project Audit Events I see just on event and the Author is me. I mean, since I created this project I am assuming that am the owner.

Comment: Tag and branches are not the same thing in Git... Go under settings -> protected branches, you should see `master` at the bottom. There will be a button that allow unprotecting it. But this won't fix your problem since you're telling me you're owner of the branch.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that GitLab does not allow you to push directly to `master`. This is a common practice. Instead, you should create a merge request from your feature branch to master. When you accept the merge request in the GitLab UI, it will automatically create a merge commit and move the `master` branch.

Comment: Although this is absolutely good practice, this is a really partial answer as it does not explain why the push is refused and the protection mechanism that can be bypassed if absolutely needed (if your are master/owner, if you remove protection...).

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks for the feedback. I'm not familiar with GitLab, so I don't know the exact protection mechanism or how to get around it.

Comment: This has been addressed in several other answers since then.